# HAProxy SSL termination + client certificate validation + curl / java client

Tags: java, ssl, curl, haproxy, keytool

I would like to have SSL termination on HAProxy, using my own self-signed certificates, and to validate client access using client certificates I create.

I create the server (which is also the CA) certificates the following way:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 1024
openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt
```

and:

```
cat ca.crt ca.key > haproxy.pem
```

at HAProxy, I configure:
bind *:443 ssl crt /path/server.pem ca-file /path/ca.crt verify required crt-ignore-err all

I create the client certificates in a similar way:

```
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -signkey ca.key -out client.crt
cat client.crt client.key > client.pem
```

My logic is: I'm creating a client key, a certificate signing request for it, and then I sign it using the CA (which is also the server certificate, so there's a simple chain that the server would recognize).

To test, I first try with the server certificate as the client cert:

```
curl https://my.service:443/ping -E ./haproxy.pem -k
pong
```

ok, it works. Now I try with the client certificate as the client certificate:

```
curl https://my.service:443/ping -E ./client.pem -k
curl: (58) unable to set private key file: './client.pem' type PEM
```

My question:
1) I would like to create a client certificate that this server will accpet, and test it using curl.
2) I would like to import this certificate and the CA into a new java keystore / truststore using keytool, so that Java (Jersey client) code could access the same content.

I have spent 2 days on 1/2.
I'm pretty sure someone that's done this before could answer this in 5m. Or so I hope. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. create client cert**

**wrong:** `openssl x509 -req -signkey` creates a *self-signed* cert, which by definition means the key *in* the cert (the subject key) is the public half of the same key whose private half signs the cert. The documentation for the cert (not req) case is clear that it replaces the key previously in the cert with the signing key. The `-req` doc is less clear, but it does the same thing; it puts in the cert the subject name from the CSR, also as the issuer, and the key from `-signkey`. You have used a CSR containing the client name, but a `-signkey` containing the CA key, producing an unusable chimera.

**right:** to sign a "child" (not self-signed) cert with `x509`, use `-CA` and possibly `-CAkey` as described in the documentation https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#SIGNING-OPTIONS (or `man [where] x509` on any Unix with openssl doc installed). If there is or ever will be more than one child cert for a given CA (defined by its DN), either use the serial-number file scheme to automatically and conveniently assign sequential serial numbers, or use `-set_serial` to manually assign unique serial numbers (sequential is the easiest way to do unique, but if you a prefer another way that's okay).

**aside:** for the self-signed CA (and server?!) cert, you don't need separate `req -new` and `x509 -req -signkey` steps, you can do it in one `req -new -x509`. See the doc/manpage for `req`. In fact you don't need a separate `genrsa` step, `req -newkey [-nodes] -x509` can do that as well. One note: in OpenSSL 1.0.0+ this generates the generic PKCS#8 format keyfile instead of the "legacy" PKCS#1 format used by `genrsa` (and `rsa`); all OpenSSL functions can accept either, but some other things might not. In particular last I checked (a while ago) the Wireshark option to decrypt SSL/TLS using server key for akRSA (there are other options too) accepted only PKCS#1 not PKCS#8.

**2. use in Java (Jersey).** Note that *any* SSL/TLS client doing client authentication, including Java, needs both the certificate *and the privatekey*, and in most cases the certificate uses "chain" or "intermediate" certs which you need also. Some people (cough) Microsoft (cough) encourage you to misunderstand and ignore this important distinction, but if you try to use only a certificate it won't work at all. On the other hand a *truststore* entry needs only the certificate, almost always only the *root* (CA) certificate, and usually *must* have only the certificate. Your situation where the same person operates the CA *and* server *and* client(s) is somewhat unusual for PKC.

**2a. maybe just convert to pkcs12.** Java does not directly support the openssl format(s) for keys, but both Java and openssl support PKCS#12 (and so do Microsoft, Mozilla, Apple, and probably others). Since you combined client key and (leaf) cert in `client.pem` do

```
openssl pkcs12 -export <client.pem -CA ca.crt [-name whatever] >client.p12
# if you use separate key,cert files see the doc about -in and -inkey
```

Java crypto (JCE and JSSE) can use this PKCS#12 as a keystore, *if* you can configure the keystore "type" (as pkcs12). The default `SSLSocketFactory` supports this, and so do other apps I've used, but I don't use Jersey and don't know what it does here. PKCS#12 isn't generally supported to carry "separate" certs (without privatekey), but in your case the CA cert for the client is *also* the cert for the server, so it will happen to work as your truststore as well; otherwise you would need to import the server CA or server selfsigned cert (only cert not privatekey) into a JKS truststore (which might be the default truststore in JRE/lib/security/[jsse]cacerts).

**2b. maybe further convert to JKS.** If Jersey cannot use PKCS#12 directly, Java can convert it to JKS which *any* sane Java code can use, like:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore client.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore client.jks
```

UPDATE 2018: after this answer was written Java support of PKCS12 increased, making it less often necessary to convert to JKS. 8u60 released fall 2017 and up still defaults to keystore type JKS, but as a special feature(?) type JKS can actually read (though not write) PKCS12; see [the release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u60-relnotes-2620227.html) and item `keystore.type.compat` in file `JRE/lib/security/java.security`. Java9 released 2017 makes the default keystore type PKCS12 which (as expected) reads and writes PKCS12, although explicit JKS no longer reads PKCS12. But if you do need to convert with Java9 for some reason, you now need to specify `-deststoretype jks` but no longer need to specify `-srcstoretype pkcs12`.

Comment: Thank you!  Let's start over, wipe the slate clean. I would like to create a CA, server cert, and client cert. I don't mind if the server cert (haproxy) is the CA cert, but since I'm diving into this, I would like to do the most logical thing that works. I would like curl and Java client to use the client cert, and haproxy to verify it. What would be the best way to achieve that? Can you please specify the correct sequence of steps?

Comment: btw: Found https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Web_Services_Security_Guide/files/i305191.html and https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Web_Services_Security_Guide/files/i382664.html and I was able to create the certs and curl. I was even able to import the cert to the java keystore, but still Java fails on ssl handshake.

Comment: @JRun that's a substantially changed question; it's a judgement call, but I'd say it's more change than SE likes in an answered question, because the goal is that *anyone* with the (original) problem can find the question and answer. Therefore I suggest you ask a *new* question with what you are *now* doing and exactly what the problem is; "still fails" is useless to solve a problem. It *is*I arguably better if the server cert is not the CA cert (more manageable) and is issued by same CA (which client needs as prover anyway).